# Static fields question

Tags: c#, static, get, set, field

im trying to understand the get and set properties for fields, and run in to this issue, can somone explaine to me why i had to make the int X field Static to make this work?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int X = 30;
        public static void Main()
        {
            var cX = new testme();
            cX.intX = 12;
            Console.WriteLine(cX.intX);
            cX.intX = X;
            Console.WriteLine(cX.intX);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class testme
    {
        public int intX
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you were using the field in a static context, in this case the method `public`**`static`**`void Main`. Since your `Program` class just runs statically there is no instance and therefore you can't access any instance members.

Answer (score 0):

because it is used in a static method

Answer (score 0):

Since `Main` is static, you cannot access non-static instances from outside of it.

Comment: Sure you can. Accessibility and staticness have nothing to do with each other.